# How to get User info via FB Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am finding the way to get user info by using the FB Graph API.

In my app when i get my friends list it shows me 403 friends from graph API, But actually there are 408 friends in my fb account friends section, but when i rewuest by using Graph API it gives me 402 friends records only.

Is it possible that Graph API doesn't give accurate friends list?

Answer (score 1):

Probably means that some of your friends have 'opted out' of their data being made available to any 3rd party apps.

Comment: Thanks Robert for the reply, but what type of the settings that we can set in FB for these kinda options?